# How can I remove the [,] symbols from the result of ArrayList.toString()?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a method which returns an ArrayList in my Android app. Everything works great, but one thing annoys the heck out of me. When I print out the ArrayList in my TextView it looks like this:

```
[firstValue
, secondValue
, thirdValue
]
```

How can I remove `[` and `,` from the output?

Comment: How are you printing it out in your TextView?

Comment: Why are you printing the list in a TextView?

Comment: Because it contains the values I need to print out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want this:

```
public String formatList(List<?> list) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(Object o : list) {
        b.append(o);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

The `toString()` method of the lists (and other collections) is mainly for debugging output.

Answer (score 2):

This is coming from ArrayList's toString() method (or some underlying collection's toString()).  If it's bugging you that much, extend ArrayList and override toString().  But because it's just debugging output, I'd personally try and get over your anxiety.  ;)

Comment: Would you want to send in an app with that kind of output? :-)

Comment: One typically doesn't use toString() to generate actual application output.  You CAN, but it's usually meant for debugging purposes.  So, no, I wouldn't send in an app with that output.  I'd create another method tailored to produce the exact output that I want.  ;)